# Passing shell script file

Tags: plink, esxi

I have a linux shell script file which collects various data from linux server. (Services, Process, FreeSpace etc.).

From windows to collect the data we are using Plink to connect to linux Boxes and run the shell script

```
plink root@servername -pw Password -noagent -m Batch-File.
```

and using pscp to copy the file to windows location.

Now when I try to do the same for Esxi  the plink command fails with the error below.

> FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection

though If i give a direct command as below.

```
plink root@servername -pw Password -noagent  ls /etc
```

works out.

Let me know how to use the plink for esxi .. if possible.

Comment: Well after seeing the messages log it looks like that the issue is with esxi's  limitation to read long character string. The message log fails in the session with String Too Long and then post a message of closing the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the messages log it looks like that the issue is with esxi's limitation to read long character string. The message log fails in the session with String Too Long and then post a message of closing the connection.

Thus the approach was to copy the shell script as a pscp connection, run the file with executable permission and collect the data gathered and delete the file from system.